# Why am I unable to store form input in a session?

Tags: php

I'm trying to save the input from my form in a session. I have this code in index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $_SESSION['str1'] = $_POST["streamer1"];
    $_SESSION['str2']   = $_POST["streamer2"];
} 
?>

<form method="post" action="view.php" id="steamerEingabe">      
    <label class="white-text font-weight-light">Streamer #1</label>
    <center><input type="text" name="streamer1" class="form-control"></input></center><br>

    <label class="white-text font-weight-light">Streamer #2</label>
    <center><input type="text" name="streamer2" class="form-control"></input></center><br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-cyan">Watch Now</button>  
</form>
```

And now I want to work with this session in my view.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['str1'];
echo $_SESSION['str2'];   
session_destroy();
?>
```

But this does not work. I get these errors

```
Notice: Undefined index: str1 in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/multistream/view.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: str2 in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/multistream/view.php on line 5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That session is not going to exist all the time, you need to make sure it's actually set like you did the server request method in the other file

Comment: check value of $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] that is value equal to "POST" (capital) and touch if condition codes.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail please? Where I need to add what? Thx ;)

Comment: @VahidMoghadam i already do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is this: `action="view.php"`

Your form is submitting directly to `view.php`, but the code that sets the session values is in the same file with the form.

Instead, you can submit the form to the same page (index.php), and redirect to view.php after setting the session values if the form is submitted.

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $_SESSION['str1'] = $_POST["streamer1"];
    $_SESSION['str2']   = $_POST["streamer2"];
    header('Location: view.php');                // redirect after setting session values
}
?>

             <!-- submit to self -->
<form method="post" action="" id="steamerEingabe">
    <label class="white-text font-weight-light">Streamer #1</label>
    <center><input type="text" name="streamer1" class="form-control"></input></center><br>

    <label class="white-text font-weight-light">Streamer #2</label>
    <center><input type="text" name="streamer2" class="form-control"></input></center><br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-cyan">Watch Now</button>
</form>
```

If you make these changes, view.php should work as expected. But you should still check that those session values are set before using them. If you go to view.php directly without submitting the form in index.php, they probably won't be there.